# How to use Pointers correctly in Golang

Tags: go

I am new to the `go` language and am in a scenario where my program works but not sure whether I should have used pointers or not.

Here is my program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Shape interface {
    getVolume() float64
}

type Cube struct {
    Side float64
}

type RectanglePrism struct {
    Length float64
    Width  float64
    Height float64
}


func main() {
    c := Cube{Side: 3}
    r := RectanglePrism{Length: 4, Width: 3, Height: 3}
    fmt.Println(Volume(c))
    fmt.Println(Volume(r))

}

func (c Cube) getVolume() float64 {
    return math.Pow(c.Side, 3)
}

func Volume(s Shape) float64 {
    return s.getVolume()
}

func (r RectanglePrism) getVolume() float64 {
    return r.Length * r.Width * r.Height
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/LKSvJXNCEbQ

As you can see `Volume` does not modify values in `c`, just does a calculation and therefore it doesn't  necessarily need to **point** to the original value - nonetheless it does a copy which is more expensive

My questions are:

- `getVolume()` should receive a pointer to `Cube` and `RectangularPrism`?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Aim here is to right efficient code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"it does a copy which is more expensive "* Is it? Can we see the benchmarks on which you're basing that statement?

Comment: I haven’t run any benchmarks this is what pretty much every book on golang claims. This is a simple example I am using to clarify some concepts

Comment: *"if so, then how can I create getVolume() with a generic pointer? If this make sense."* It doesn't. What do you mean by generic pointer? And why do you think you need one in the first place?

Comment: Read the first 7 words....

Comment: "what pretty much every book on golang claims". No. No professional book on Go ever would make such a claim (which is very likely to be plain wrong).

Comment: The little Go Book page 29

Comment: @Altons I've read them, with my comment I was trying to elicit an explanation of what you mean by *"generic pointer"*, unfortunately the first 7 words *"I am new to the go language"* do not provide an explanation that can help me better understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/t3_Xzhq88g-

Comment: @SivaGuru thanks. Is this the preference over my approach or is it just another way?

Comment: well you said like you wanted to pass as pointers... the approach i used  is the way you pass pointer.. you are passing it as value.

Comment: I think my question was on whether I should have pointers or not and better off what is the “go” way

Comment: @Altons note that both `Cube` and `RectanglePrism` are small enough that attempting to make the "correct" pointer-vs-value choice *based* on the performance of copy would be considered, at least by me, to be poor allocation of resources. In addition to that, while it's reasonable to assume that copying an 8 byte pointer is faster than, say, copying 16 byte value, it might be also reasonable to assume that reading/writing a field through a pointer receiver rather than a value receiver is gonna be slower. One could be a lot farther than the other in terms of memory location.

Comment: that's a general kinda question... if your application uses a very late data like passing 10000 lines of string to a lot of function then your application will be slow as you are passing it as value.. but if there is no use-case like then you can do it the normal way... the method i used is also a "go" way.. for small data it won't make a difference

Comment: would you say both methods are correct but one is less efficient?

Comment: both methods are correct... but if you are handling huge amounts of data I would suggest the pointer method I used..

Comment: @SivaGuru thanks - if you bother you write a detailed answer I will accept it. Thanks again

Comment: Your largest data structure here is 24 bytes, which is well under the size of a single cpu cache line. Copying this is almost always going to be faster than dereferencing a pointer, and performance will depend completely on data locality and access patterns. Use pointers where they make _logical_ sense and don't try to optimize things where you don't yet have a problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As defined in this https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers

if you are modifying data in the struct or handling huge amounts of data or if your struct is very huge its better to use a pointer.

as in the above cases, if you are passing it by the value it makes a difference as through each function call you pass a new copy of the struct which might affect your application's efficiency.

for very small data  passing it by value or pointer won't make a difference as the difference would be negligible(like in your example it won't make a difference) https://play.golang.org/p/t3_Xzhq88g-

if you decide on a way to call function all your other functions will also have to be called in a similar fashion.

so analyse your use case (these are some suggestive uses cases there might be more scenarios)

1) are you gonna modify data in the struct

2) is the data gonna be huge

3) or if the struct is gonna be huge

4) are you gonna return the modified values (like in your example)

and based you these you can use a pointer or pass-by-value